# Variable with NaN value is not equal to itself in Ruby

Tags: ruby, equality, nan

I was testing some of mine Ruby 1.9 code when I've stumbled across something that is very interesting. I'm hoping that someone can explain why is this happening.

Here is the code:

```
inf = Float::INFINITY

x = inf - inf
y = 0.0/0.0

puts "X is #{x}"
puts "Y is #{y}"

puts "X and Y are both NaN." if x.nan? && y.nan?

puts "This is all as we expected, but here is the mystery..."

puts "X is not equal to Y." if x == y

puts "Surprisingly not even X is equal to X." if x == x
```

And this is the output:

```
X is NaN
Y is NaN
X and Y are both NaN.
This is all as we expected, but here is the mystery...
```

I have assigned a NaN value in two different ways to two variables and when I've tested if they were equal that was not the case. After that I've tested if one variable is equal to itself and even that wasn't true. It's logical to expect that some value is equal to itself but as we can se, it just isn't.

I don't know if this is the right way to test NaN values, but I would really like to know what is behind all of this and is there a reason for a Ruby to behave like this?

Thank you

Comment: Note that this behavior is not specific to Ruby, but mandated by the IEEE floating point standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we think about it, it seems logical. You get `x` by subtracting one infinitely large number from another infinitely large number? What's the result of that? We don't know.

How can we compare things that we don't know?

To backup my logic, here's the source of `Float#==`

```
static VALUE flo_eq(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    volatile double a, b;

    switch (TYPE(y)) {
      case T_FIXNUM:
        b = (double)FIX2LONG(y);
        break;
      case T_BIGNUM:
        b = rb_big2dbl(y);
        break;
      case T_FLOAT:
        b = RFLOAT_VALUE(y);
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1300
        if (isnan(b)) return Qfalse;
#endif
        break;
      default:
        return num_equal(x, y);
    }
    a = RFLOAT_VALUE(x);
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1300
    if (isnan(a)) return Qfalse;
#endif
    return (a == b)?Qtrue:Qfalse;
}
```

Comment: The most interesting bit about this code are the conditional compilation directives to return `Qfalse` on Windows.

Comment: Yeah, that got my attention too. Digging deeper :)

Comment: I just assumed this means that older versions of the MS C compiler treated two `NaN`s as equal...

Comment: @MichaelKohl: i was trying to find where this "NaN is not equal to NaN" logic is located. Seems that it's in C compiler :)

Comment: It's defined in IEEE 754 AFAIK. BTW: try `0 * 0/0.0`, `0 ** 0/0.0` and `0/0.0 ** 0` in IRB if you are looking for some interesting reading today :-)

Comment: @MichaelKohl: maybe tomorrow. Going to sleep mode now.

Comment: Yes, that actually sounds like a good logic to me. But to have an object on the left side of equality operator which has the same name, object_id and value as the object on the right side and to have a false result was a real surprise to me. I guess logic is not always so logical. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make the exact same code in Javascript:

```
x = Infinity - Infinity
y = 0/0
if(!(x==y)) alert("Not equal");
if(!(x==x)) alert("Not equal");
```

It will have the exact same behavior. And this behavior is expected. Two NaN's are not equal between themselves. Infinity - Infinity is not the same thing as [One huge number] - [The same huge number], they are two different huge numbers. Nobody knows the result of this operation. So, this is a NaN.

So, this is not a mistake. This is mathematically plausible.

Also, try

```
if(!(NaN==NaN)) alert("Not equal");
if(!(NaN===NaN)) alert("Not equal");
```

NaN will never be equal to anything.

Comment: I was just thinking about something... Infinity is equal to Infinity in Ruby and if the language sais that they are the two same huge numbers then Infinity-Infinity should be equal to another Infinity-Infinity, right? :) So the new question is, why Infinity==Infinity if it represents two different huge numbers, as you say?

Comment: Infinity minus infinity is mathematically undefined. It's not a number per se, so assuming it follows numerical properties is a fallacy: http://www.philforhumanity.com/Infinity_Minus_Infinity.html As for equality, I assume Ruby just compares two pointers for equality.

Comment: @j-milan ok, simplifying, see here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/infinity.html - there is a bunch of mathematical operations you can do with Infinity, and all of them are mathematically defined. `∞ = ∞` because `x + ∞ = ∞`. If `x = 0`, then `∞ = ∞`.